# Signifincance of trailer of the trailer?

Tags: film-industry, trailers

There's a trend nowadays to make a *trailer of the trailer*. At least for media like youtube.

Why are the studios doing this? What's the point of adding a 5 seconds intro to the trailer I'm about to see? In fact, this intros sometimes are even spoiling the climax of the trailer.

Here is an example:

Comment: I always hated this concept... Now we have to watch a teaser of a teaser which is a teaser to the trailer of the movie...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's elaborated pretty well in [The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2016/4/22/11487410/movie-trailers-independence-day-jason-bourne):

> The burgeoning trend of teasers within trailers exist purely to retain the viewer's attention **in that exact moment**.
>
> Take for example, the trailer for Independence Day: Resurgence; the first 10 seconds are visually arresting — an alien ship turning Earth's atmosphere into flames, an upside-down skyscraper skewering a city like a giant dart. But the images, free of context, make no sense. They're simply loud and spectacular.
>
> What follows this teaser is a (comparably) slower sales pitch, one that features the same footage, but takes time to explain what is happening in the scenes and why.
>
> The teaser within the trailer speaks to a moment in which we have so many distractions and choices that marketers must sell us on giving a trailer three minutes of our time.

It's a era when we get so many hyped big budget film trailer every other day and we have chance to skip this one and play some other trailer, this teaser before trailer give chance to user to know what they signed up for in-advance to keep them engaged.

Comment: Also, these 10-seconds trailers are mostly used on commercial displays in public places (train stations, department stores...), such as [this one](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/maquette-verticale-d-affiche-de-caisson-lumineux-%C3%A0-la-station-train-106855844.jpg). Most of time, these displays provide no sound and the 10-second span is enough to suscitate curiosity for people passing by, thus generating hype for the trailer itself.